# How can I searching for different variants of bioinformatics motifs in string, using Perl?

Tags: perl, string, bioinformatics

I have a program output with one [tandem repeat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_repeat) in different variants. Is it possible to search (in a string) for the [motif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_motif) and to tell the program to find all variants with maximum "3" mismatches/insertions/deletions?

Comment: Not every one who knows Perl 5 knows the domain specific terms you are using.  I have added links to help us understand your question, please check that they correctly define the terms you are using.

Comment: the link for the tandem repeats is okay. thanks. With motif I meant a nucleotide sequence like "CGTCGCACAG" which can appear like this "CATGGCACGG" (3 mismatches). I would like the program to find all the variants and that I dont need to search for everyone... Anja

Comment: How are the sequences delimited? ie, you say you have them all in a string, are they surrounded by quotes like this: `"CGTCGCACAG" "CATGGCACGG" etc, Do you need to know the position of them or just the count?

Comment: The string is just a sequence of nucleotids (5428 basepairs). I would like to know that e.g. the motif "CATGGCACGG" is located from bp 823 to 832  - Anja

Comment: Are you looking for all n-grams between two inputs with a hamming distance <= 3? Glancing at your links, I haven't the faintest idea what a tandem repeat or a motif is, formally stated. It looks like motifs aren't even formally defined in terms of an algorithmical predicate... There is an established mathematical vocabulary for string analysis. When framed in the established vocabulary, you can probably find an algorithm that you (yourself) can implement. I highly suggest you look into string matching texts.

Comment: I wrote a program that does exactly this back in 2004, but you have to specify more than just the number of mistakes, because otherwise, you just get junk back. You have to give it a number of mistakes allowed within a unit (as a maximum number of mistakes) and a number of mistakes allowed within a window of units.  So 3 mistakes per unit allowed, but only 5 allowed per 6 units. My code is really inefficient however. I would totally do it a different way if I did it again.

Answer (score 4):

The following program generates a string of 2 character pairs 5,428 pairs long in an array of 1,000 elements long. I realize it is more likely that you will be reading these from a file, but this is just an example. Obviously you would replace the random strings with your actual data from whatever source.

I do not know if `'AT','CG','TC','CA','TG','GC','GG'` that I used are legitimate base pair combinations or not. (I slept through biology...) Just edit the `map` block pairs to legitimate pairs and change the `7` to the number of pairs if you want to generate legitimate random strings for testing.

If the substring at the `offset` point is 3 differences or less, the array element (a scalar value) is stored in an anonymous array in the value part of a hash. The key part of the hash is the substring that is a near match. Rather than array elements, the values could be file names, Perl data references or other relevant references you want to associate with your motif.

While I have just looked at character by character differences between the strings, you can put any specific logic that you need to look at by replacing the line `foreach my $j (0..$#a1) { $diffs++ unless ($a1[$j] eq $a2[$j]); }` with the comparison logic that works for your problem. I do not know how `mismatches/insertions/deletions` are represented in your string, so I leave that as an exercise to the reader. Perhaps [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm) or [String::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eyappo/String-Diff-0.04/lib/String/Diff.pm) from CPAN?

It is easy to modify this program to have keyboard input for `$target` and `$offset` or have the string searched beginning to end rather than several strings at a fixed offset.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @bps;
push(@bps,join('',map { ('AT','CG','TC','CA','TG','GC','GG')[rand 7] } 
       0..5428)) for(1..1_000);

my $len=length($bps[0]);
my $s_count= scalar @bps;

print "$s_count random strings generated $len characters long\n" ;

my $target="CGTCGCACAG";
my $offset=832;
my $nlen=length $target;
my %HoA;
my $diffs=0;
my @a2=split(//, $target);
substr($bps[-1], $offset, $nlen)=$target; #guarantee 1 match
substr($bps[-2], $offset, $nlen)="CATGGCACGG"; #anja example

foreach my $i (0..$#bps) {
    my $cand=substr($bps[$i], $offset, $nlen);
    my @a1=split(//, $cand);
    $diffs=0;
    foreach my $j (0..$#a1) { $diffs++ unless ($a1[$j] eq $a2[$j]); }
    next if $diffs > 3;
    push (@{$HoA{$cand}}, $i); 
}

foreach my $hit (keys %HoA) {
    my @a1=split(//, $hit);
    $diffs=0;
    my $ds="";
    foreach my $j (0..$#a1) { 
        if($a1[$j] eq $a2[$j]) {
            $ds.=" ";
        } else {
            $diffs++;
            $ds.=$a1[$j];
        }
    }   
    print "Target:       $target\n",
          "Candidate:    $hit\n",
          "Differences:  $ds       $diffs differences\n",
          "Array element: ";
    foreach (@{$HoA{$hit}}) {
         print "$_ " ;
     }
     print "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1000 random strings generated 10858 characters long
Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CGTCGCACAG
Differences:                   0 differences
Array element: 999 

Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CGTCGCCGCG
Differences:        CGC        3 differences
Array element: 696 

Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CGTCGCCGAT
Differences:        CG T       3 differences
Array element: 851 

Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CGTCGCATGG
Differences:         TG        2 differences
Array element: 986 

Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CATGGCACGG
Differences:   A G    G        3 differences
Array element: 998 

..several cut out.. 

Target:       CGTCGCACAG
Candidate:    CGTCGCTCCA
Differences:        T CA       3 differences
Array element: 568 926
```

Comment: The variant between 823 and 832 was just an example, between this one cant lay something else. The other variants are located somewhere else in the string... So I can't tell the program to look for this motif in different variants?

Comment: Sure, it can be indexed to any offset you want. The only thing I don't understand is "deletions" Does this mean that "CGTCGCACAG" might become shorter? From a Perl perspective, this is easy if the string is fixed length or delimited in some way. If you need to go through the string and interpret base pairs and infer what happened, that is harder. See the difference?

Comment: okay, I think I can ignore deletion as I don't have gaps in my sequence. So the only important thing is mismatch (e.g. from G to A). The only limitation is given by the motif (it has always the same length) as I give it through the keyboard. Then the program should search for the different variants (with maximum 3 mismatches)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are routines for this sort of thing in BioPerl.

In any case, you might get better answers if you asked this over at [BioStar, the bioinformatics stack exchange](http://biostar.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

When I was in my first couple years of learning perl, I wrote what I now consider to be a very inefficient (but functional) tandem repeat finder (which used to be available on my old job's company website) called tandyman.  I wrote a fuzzy version of it a couple years later called cottonTandy.  If I were to re-write it today, I would use hashes for a global search (given the allowed mistakes) and utilize pattern matching for a local search.

Here's an example of how you use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tandyman;

$sequence = "ATGCATCGTAGCGTTCAGTCGGCATCTATCTGACGTACTCTTACTGCATGAGTCTAGCTGTACTACGTACGAGCTGAGCAGCGTACgTG";

my $tandy = Tandyman->new(\$sequence,'n'); #Can't believe I coded it to take a scalar reference! Prob. fresh out of a cpp class when I wrote it.

$tandy->SetParams(4,2,3,3,4);
#The parameters are, in order:
# repeat unit size
# min number of repeat units to require a hit
# allowed mistakes per unit (an upper bound for "mistake concentration")
# allowed mistakes per window (a lower bound for "mistake concentration")
# number of units in a "window"

while(@repeat_info = $tandy->FindRepeat())
  {print(join("\t",@repeat_info),"\n")}
```

The output of this test looks like this (and takes a horrendous 11 seconds to run):

```
25  32  TCTA    2   0.87    TCTA TCTG
58  72  CGTA    4   0.81    CTGTA CTA CGTA CGA
82  89  CGTA    2   0.87    CGTA CGTG
45  51  TGCA    2   0.87    TGCA TGA
65  72  ACGA    2   0.87    ACGT ACGA
23  29  CTAT    2   0.87    CAT CTAT
36  45  TACT    3   0.83    TACT CT TACT
24  31  ATCT    2   1   ATCT ATCT
51  59  AGCT    2   0.87    AGTCT AGCT
33  39  ACGT    2   0.87    ACGT ACT
62  72  ACGT    3   0.83    ACT ACGT ACGA
80  88  ACGT    2   0.87    AGCGT ACGT
81  88  GCGT    2   0.87    GCGT ACGT
63  70  CTAC    2   0.87    CTAC GTAC
32  38  GTAC    2   0.87    GAC GTAC
60  74  GTAC    4   0.81    GTAC TAC GTAC GAGC
23  30  CATC    2   0.87    CATC TATC
71  82  GAGC    3   0.83    GAGC TGAGC AGC
1   7   ATGC    2   0.87    ATGC ATC
54  60  CTAG    2   0.87    CTAG CTG
15  22  TCAG    2   0.87    TCAG TCGG
70  81  CGAG    3   0.83    CGAG CTGAG CAG
44  50  CATG    2   0.87    CTG CATG
25  32  TCTG    2   0.87    TCTA TCTG
82  89  CGTG    2   0.87    CGTA CGTG
55  73  TACG    5   0.75    TAGCTG TAC TACG TACG AG
69  83  AGCG    4   0.81    ACG AGCTG AGC AGCG
15  22  TCGG    2   0.87    TCAG TCGG
```

As you can see, it allows indels and SNPs.  The columns are, in order:

1. Start position
2. Stop position
3. Consensus sequence
4. The number of units found
5. A quality metric out of 1
6. The repeat units separated by spaces

Note, that it's easy to supply parameters (as you can see from the output above) that will output junk/insignificant "repeats", but if you know how to supply good params, it can find what you set it upon finding.

Unfortunately, the package is not publicly available.  I never bothered to make it available since it's so slow and not amenable to even prokaryotic-sized genome searches (though it would be workable for individual genes).  In my novice coding days, I had started to add a feature to take a "state" as input so that I could run it on sections of a sequence in parallel and I never finished that once I learned hashes would make it so much faster.  By that point, I had moved on to other projects.  But if it would suit your needs, message me, I can email you a copy.

It's just shy of 1000 lines of code, but it has lots of bells & whistles, such as the allowance of IUPAC ambiguity codes (BDHVRYKMSWN).  It works for both amino acids and nucleic acids.  It filters out internal repeats (e.g. does not report TTTT or ATAT as 4nt consensuses).